# Format echo depending on array

Tags: php

I have this code that finds who is logged in and displays the usernames and their member status.

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($whoisloggedin)) {
        $usersArray = $row['status'];    
        $usersArray2 = $row['username'];
        echo '<pre>';
        echo $usersArray," ",$usersArray2;
        echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Now that displays 4 usernames as there are 4 users logged in, I want to know if it's possible to change the text colour. So it might currently say "Admin Kenazz" or "VIP ryemck", I want to know if I can make it so the "Admin" is red, "VIP" is gold etc?

I

Comment: You can do it...You can print one by one element of array & apply style to particular elment(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($whoisloggedin)) {
    $usersArray = $row['status'];    
    $usersArray2 = $row['username'];

    if ($usersArray == 'Admin') {
        $colour = 'red';
    }
    else if ($usersArray == 'VIP') {
        $colour = 'gold';
    }

    echo '<p style="color: '.$colour.'">'.$usersArray.' '.$usersArray2.'</p>';
}
```

Comment: as said below, I think that `if`...`else` is not the best choice, since after a couple more cases it will become unmaintainable. Good use of the the `$color` variable though! Plus, a default case is missing.

Comment: @hexblot Thanks for your contribution :) but there's only going to be 1, maybe 2 more cases

Comment: @hexblot Yeh a switch would also be a good way of doing it, although if there was going to be a lot more I would just make a css class for each one so neither an if statement or switch would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply a check

```
if($row['somthing'] == 'Admin') {
  echo '<span style="color:red">'.$row['username'].'</span>';
}
else if($row['somthing'] == 'VIP') {
  echo '<span style="color:#fff">'.$row['username'].'</span>';
}
else {
  echo '<span style="color:#f00">'.$row['username'].'</span>';
}
```

and so on....

Comment: `if`...`else` will get very tedious very fast, `switch` might be better here. Plus you don't have a default case. Otherwise, solid solution!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do it with replace function or named array keys:

```
$rename=array("Admin"=>"<span style='color:red'>"
,"VIP"=>"<span style='color:yellow'>");  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($whoisloggedin)) {
    $usersArray = $row['status'];    
    $usersArray2 = $row['username'];
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $rename[$usersArray].$usersArray" ".$usersArray2."</span>";
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Now second variant using replace function

```
$find=array("Admin","VIP");  
$replace=array("<span style='color:red'>Admin"
,"<span style='color:yellow'>VIP");  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($whoisloggedin)) {
    $usersArray = $row['status'];    
    $usersArray2 = $row['username'];
    echo '<pre>';
    echo str_replace($find,$replace,$usersArray)." ".$usersArray2."</span>";
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: this is very close to being hard to maintain with only two cases! Please see either my or @David Jones answer for a much more scalable solution.

Comment: the questions contains "admin is red, vip gold, ETC" which indicates that there is much more cases than just two. In such case this code is much more readable than other answers

Comment: @Kybored I beg to differ - `switch` is a way better construct for a greater number of cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is HTML output, not console, you can try something similar to :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($whoisloggedin) ) {
  $usersArray = $row['status'];    
  $usersArray2 = $row['username'];

  print '<pre>';
  switch( $usersArray ) {
    case 'something':
      $color = "red";
      break;
    case 'somethingelse':
      $color = "blue"
      break;
    default:
      $color = "white";
      break;
  }
  print '<span style="color: '.$color.'">'.$usersArray.' '.$usersArray2.'</span>';
  print '</pre>'
}
```

Obviously, it will be better to replace the `style` tag with a class, and add the colors to CSS - such as

```
print '<span class="'.$color.'">';
```

With a CSS line similar to

```
span.blue { color: blue; }
```

**Edit:** Incorporated the $color variable as per @David Jones solution